# Best way to list Alphabetical(A-Z) using PHP

Tags: php

I need to print/list alphabetical(A-Z) chararcters to manage Excel cells. Is there any PHP function to list alphabetic?

I need result as

```
A1
B1
C1
D1
...
...
```

OR

```
A
B
C
...
...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can either do:

```
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char) {
    echo $char . "\n";
}
```

Or:

```
for ($char = 'A'; $char <= 'Z'; $char++) {
    echo $char . "\n";
}
```

Comment: @VeckHsiao Just use interlaced loops.

Comment: @VeckHsiao have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13672617/1990745

Comment: The second form does not work in PHP 7.3 and probably not in PHP 7.x.

Answer (score 15):

[`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) supports letters since PHP 4.1, so you can do this:

```
$azRange = range('A', 'Z');
foreach ($azRange as $letter)
{
  print("$letter\n");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in this way as well: ASCII range used here.

```
for($i = 65 ; $i<=90; $i++)
{
  echo chr($i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**I made a constant time function as follows**

*This function gives the Alphabetic representation of a numeric index*

```
public static $alpha = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];

public static function getColName($index){
  $index--;
  $nAlphabets = 26;
  $f = floor($index/pow($nAlphabets,0)) % $nAlphabets;
  $s = (floor($index/pow($nAlphabets,1)) % $nAlphabets)-1;
  $t = (floor($index/pow($nAlphabets,2)) % $nAlphabets)-1;

  $f = $f < 0 ? '' : self::$alpha[$f];
  $s = $s < 0 ? '' : self::$alpha[$s];
  $t = $t < 0 ? '' : self::$alpha[$t];

  return trim("{$t}{$s}{$f}");

}
```

Now if you want to use it create a range. you can call this function in a loop pushing your values to an array.

As for most of the time, we need the representation rather than a range this function would work just fine.

**HOW TO USE**

Just enclose these static functions in a class and use it as

```
className::getColName(47);
```

> **Making a range in my case was a waste of memory.**

Comment: It is not a waste of processor however.  And if it has a technical merit that is escaping me, it comes with the flaw of being unreadable, and more importantly, it has the inconvenient of not corresponding to the requirements set by the topic. Unless there are excel cells that correspond to an empty string or a combination of two letters. But those that have two letters also require a number for rows.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the [range function](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
$a=range("A","Z");
foreach($a as $char)
    echo $char."\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
$range = range("A", "Z");
for ($i=1; i<=100; i++) {
    foreach ($range as $letter) {
      print("$letter$i\n");
    }
}
```

will print you all the combinations:
A1
B1
C1
...
...
...
...
V100
W100
Z100

Modify the ranges accordingly to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

here's my code for HTML using P.H.P code, and it works fine

```
for($i = 'a' ; $i <= 'z' ; $i++){
echo $i. "<br />"; }
```

Comment: Believe it or not this actually works for me as I need to increment letters by 1 just as you did here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this code results your requirements....

```
<?php 
        $x= 'A';
            for($i=0;$i<26;$i++)
            {
                echo $x."<br/>";//generates A,B,C,D...Z
                $x++;
                if($i == 25)
                {
                    $x = 'A';
                    $y = '1';
                    for($j=0;$j<26;$j++)
                    {
                        echo $x.$y."<br />";//generates A1,B1...Z1
                        $x++;
                        if($j == 25)
                        { 
                            $x = 'A';
                            $y++;
                            for($k=0;$k<26;$k++)
                            {
                               echo $x.$y."<br />";//generates A2,B2....Z2
                               $x++; 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$len = 0;
for ($char = 'A'; $char <= 'Z'; $char++) {
    $len++;
    if ($len == 26) {
        break;
    }
    echo $char;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a comprehensive set of Excel functionality, then take a look at [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) which provides a lot of methods for manipulating cell addresses and ranges, as well as reading/writing for Excel and various other spreadsheet file formats

Answer (score 0):

**This code for display A,B,...,ZY,ZZ.**

```
function print_char($end_no=90, $start_no=65, $prefix_no=0)
{ $vasant='';
    if($prefix_no==0)
    {
        for($set=$start_no; $set<=$end_no; $set++)
        {
            $vasant.=(chr($prefix_no).chr($set)).', ';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for($set=$start_no; $set<=90; $set++)
        {
            $vasant.=(chr($set)).', ';
        }
        for($pre_loop=65; $pre_loop<=$prefix_no; $pre_loop++)
        {
            for($set=$start_no; $set<=90; $set++)
            {
                if($set>=$end_no && $pre_loop==$prefix_no)
                {
                    $vasant.=(chr($pre_loop).chr($set)).'. ';
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    $vasant.=(chr($pre_loop).chr($set)).', ';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $vasant;
}


$show=print_char(90,65,90);
echo $show;
```