# PHP - loop through letters

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to loop through letters rather than numbers.

I am trying to do this using chr and the number equivalent but it doesn't seem to be happening!

I want four letter loop.

So AAAA, AAAB, AAAC etc through to ZZZZ - and yes I know this will likely take a while to execute!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Why don't you make an array of letters and then use nested loops:

```
$letters = range('A', 'Z');

foreach ($letters as $one) {
  foreach ($letters as $two) {
    foreach ($letters as $three) {
      foreach ($letters as $four) {
        echo "$one$two$three$four";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This starts at "AAAA", not "A".

Comment: @Kolink that's what the question specifies?

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 27):

```
for( $x = "AAAA"; ; $x++) {
    echo $x."\n";
    if( $x == "ZZZZ") break;
}
```

Incrementing a letter will cycle it through the alphabet similar to the column names in Excel.

Comment: That's actually incredibly unexpected/unintuitive behaviour (and a complete quirk), that "Z"++ == "AA". First time I've seen it at least.

Comment: it gets interesting when you try `for($c='a'; $c <= 'z'; $c++)` ... it stops at 'yz'

Comment: Is this somewhere documented?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this

```
$i = 'AAAA';
do {
  echo $i . "\n";
  $i++;
} while( $i !== 'AAAAA');
```