# How to iterate alphabets a-z in php?

Tags: php, loops

How can I run a loop in PHP to iterate alphabets from `a-z`?

Something like that:

```
for( $i ='a'; $i <= 'z'; $i++ ) {

    echo "<br>".$i;
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [Best way to list Alphabetical(A-Z) using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857246/best-way-to-list-alphabeticala-z-using-php)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simply use [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function of PHP

```
foreach(range('a','z') as $v){
    echo "$v \n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use range:

```
<?php
foreach(range('a','z') as $letter) 
{ 
   echo "$letter<br/>"; 
}
```

in addition you can store in array:

```
$alphas = range('a', 'z');
```